# Delphi, обучение. копирование строк файла.

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. Задали написать программу, позволяющую копировать четные/нечетные/все строки исходного текстового файла в результирующий файл. То есть программа читает текстовой файл, выводит его в Memo-поле. Потом на форме GroupBox у нас есть два флажка CheckBox, один на четные строки, другой на нечетные, и кнопка сохранить. С реализацией чтения текстового файла проблем нет. А вот дальше возникают проблемы с выделением четных/нечетных строк из memо-поля. Вот что дается нам для решения данной задачи, но из этого ясная картина не вырисовывается.

**(кнопка)  Button  OnClick Событие: нажатие кнопки**

**(memo-поле) 

    Lines[i] - Обращение к i-й строке memo-поля.Первая строка имеет индекс0.
``Clear-очищение memo-области.

Lines.Add 

Lines.LoadFromFile

Lines.Count Число строк в memo-поле.**

**(компонент-
      флажок)   CheckBox    Checked Состояние флажка: установлен (True)/сброшен (False).
        OnClick Событие: щелчок по флажку**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать данную программу.

Comment: Минимальный код-подсказка: 

    chetnoe := false; for {* перебор строк Memo *} do begin if chetnoe then {* запись в файл *} chetnoe := not chetnoe; end;

Если вы понимаете задачу, этого вам хватит)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не совсем понял задачу...
Вам сначала нада все содержимое текстового файла загрузить в Memo, затем нажать кнопку и в зависимсоти как указан флажек (четн или нечетн строки) выделить определенные строки - и куда их записать - загрузить??? Можно по пунктам расписать действия?

Вариант DelphiM0ZG я бы написал по другому
имеем 3 варианта записи : четн/ нечетн/все

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
start,N:integer;
endstrig:TStringList;
begin

{
 CheckBox1.Checked ==true => нужны четн
 CheckBox2.Checked ==true => нужны нечетн
}
//если нужны все
 if (CheckBox1.Checked)and(CheckBox2.Checked)  then
    begin
    //пользуем встроеный метод
    Memo.Lines.SaveToFile('путь к файлу');
    //выходим с процедуры
    exit;
    end
    else
    begin
    //либо чет либо нечет

    if (CheckBox1.Checked) then
      begin
      //четн
      start:=0; // опред старт поз
      //опред старт поз
      If (Odd(Memo.Lines.Count-1)) then N:=Memo.Lines.Count-2 else N:=Memo.Lines.Count-1;
      end;
    if (CheckBox2.Checked) then
      begin
      //нужны нечетн
      start:=1; // опред старт поз
      //опред старт поз
      If (Odd(Memo.Lines.Count-1)) then N:=Memo.Lines.Count-1 else N:=Memo.Lines.Count-2;
      end;
    endstring:=TstringList.Create;
    //строим цикл
    while start<=N do
      begin
      endstring.Add(Memo.Lines.Strings[start]);
      start:=start+2;//увелич на 2 ед
      end;
    endstring.SaveToFile('путь к файлу');
    //удал объект
    endstring.free;
    end;
end;
```

Разница в том что мы сначала определяем с какими строками работаем - а затем строем нужный нам цикл в котором и проделываем нужные действя, что на мой взгляд быстрее чем каждый раз в цикле проверять условие

Comment: А если добавятся еще чекбоксы? )

Comment: если по пунктам расписывать, то:
1. Загрузить текстовой файл в memo
2. CheckBox'ом выбрать "четные" или "нечетные" строки (для всех строк нужно нажать оба CheckBox'а)
3. Записать выделенные строки в новый файл.
В общем-то, вся задача...

Comment: то есть унас может быть 3 варианта записи в новый файл:
1. только четные
2. только нечетные
3 все записи

Прально?

Answer (score 2):

```
var start:integer;
begin
   if (CheckBox1.Checked) then start:=0 else start:=1;
   while start<Memo1.Lines.Count do begin
         Memo2.Lines.Add(Memo1.Lines.Strings[start]);
         inc(start,2);    
   end
end;
```

Так быстрее, не?

Comment: Этот код, пожалуй, самый короткий и быстрый. Свой код я писал наспех, поэтому задачи оптимизации перед собой не ставил, написал, как пример.

Comment: А если будет CheckBox1.Checked==true и CheckBox2.Checked==true, то есть нужно сохранить все строки в файл - то ваш код не будет работать ка кнужно.

Comment: вводишь параметр step, инициализируешь перед циклом в 1 или 2 и заменяешь inc(start,2) на inc(start,step)

Answer (score 2):

хмм...

```
for i:=1 to memo.lines.count do
begin
 //четные
 if (checkbox1.checked) and(i mod 2=0) then
  записать в файл Memo.lines[i-1];
 //не четные
 if (checkbox2.checked) and(i mod 2=1) then
  записать в файл Memo.lines[i-1];
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что этот код поможет. На этом примере я показал, как можно из одного Memo-поля записать нужные строки (чётные или нечётные) в другое. В коде есть комментарии, поэтому должно быть всё понятно.

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  i, N: LongWord; // тип данных можно использовать и Integer
begin
  Memo2.Clear; // Предварительно очищаю Memo
  {Если требуется выборка чётных строк, то следует выбирать строки
  с нечётным номером, т. к. в Memo они нумеруются с нуля,
  а из людей нумеровать что-то с нуля никто не догадается}
  N:=Memo1.Lines.Count-1; // количество строк
  For i:=0 To N Do
    If (CheckBox1.Checked) Then // Если чётной строки, то
      If (Odd(i)) Then   // Проверяю номер строки на нечётность
        Memo2.Lines.Add(Memo1.Lines.Strings[i])
      Else // для вложенного If
    Else
      If Not(Odd(i)) Then // Проверяю номер строки на чётность (0 - чётное число!)
        Memo2.Lines.Add(Memo1.Lines.Strings[i]);
end;
```

Comment: комментарий к твоему коду в моем ответе

Answer (score 0):

Нумерация строк в Tmemo начинается с 0, нумерация строк текста - с 1.
Поэтому:
Нечетные строки - start:=0,
Четные строки   - start:=1;